# Can a DNS TXT record be read by an app?

Tags: android, ios, windows, windows-phone

I would like to know if the following mobile operation systems: IOS, Android, Windows are allowing apps to make a DNS TXT record request.

I am planning to add some information in a TXT record that will be updated from time to time and would like to build an app that will read that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes it can, there's an app that does that even: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kodholken.dnslookup

However, I think your real question is not "Can a DNS TXT record be read by an app?" but rather "How?", for that I have no answer as I'm not a network expert.